# Angular 4 cannot run on Android system browser?

Tags: angular

I got white screen when I run my Angular 4 app (Just Hello World app from the tutorial) on the Android system browser but it's working on Chrome browser.

I don't know how to debug this on the Android system browser. So I have no idea what's the problem happening from?

Please help me, How to fix this thing?

Comment: when building the app use `ng build --base-href .`

Comment: @ParthGhiya, Thanks for your comment. But I don't understand about  ng build with "--base-href". 
Could you please let me know that how does the command work?

Comment: how you are building the android application ? using cli or some other tool ?

Comment: I'm build the android app by Android Studio but I'm just want to test an Angular app on general android browser which isn't chrome browser. 
By the way I already got my problem solved by uncomment core-js modules inside the polyfills.ts.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Disuan, I have this problem also. my program works very good on pc browsers, but I just see white screen on android browser. I have 16 core-js in polyfills.ts file. Which core-js should I uncomment?